# Charging and discharging Li-ion cell dynamically

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, solar-cell, buck-boost

I intend to use an [EBL 6F22](https://www.eblofficial.com/collections/9v-batteries/products/9v-usb-rechargeable-battery) 5400 mWh, 9 V Li-ion block as buffer for an USB-level solar charging station.

It comes with a micro-USB charging slot and necessary voltage regulation. Not much can be deduced from the official product page, but I have to assume that a voltage-dynamic boost converter is inside the cell in order to get the supplied 5 V to the charging voltage.

Is it possible to connect the cell's input to a buck/boost set to 5 V with an attached solar panel, while the output is connected to a typical 5 V load which draws current? The image below shows the intended use:

[image]

As mentioned, I don't have any knowledge of the battery's insides, marked in red. Will I kill the battery with this setup?

Comment: This is a Ni-MH battery, no Li-ion. With no built-in converter. Where did you see that the battery has a built-in converter?

Comment: I guess you mean these ones: https://www.eblofficial.com/collections/9v-batteries/products/9v-rechargeable-batteries - still looks like there is no converter inside

Comment: and why do you show two connections + ground, when the battery has only two terminals?

Comment: @user253751 sorry, wrong link. Edited. As i said, the battery has a micro USB-slot, which means that it has two seperate terminals. These terminals can't be connected, because an applied charging voltage of 5V would without a boost-converter not be able to charge the Li-ion cell to 8.5V.

Comment: It seems these ones: https://www.eblofficial.com/collections/9v-batteries/products/9v-usb-rechargeable-battery have the USB charging ports. Are they the ones you mean?

Comment: Yes, those ones (I just linked) will have some kind of built-in converter. I can't predict how the built-in converter will respond to different voltages. It's probably designed to draw a specific amount of current; if the solar panel (+converter) can't provide that current at 5V, it's likely the voltage will collapse to 0, as **your** converter tries to draw more and more current at lower and lower voltages to keep the output at 5V. If it was connected directly to the panel, there's at least a chance it would decrease the charging speed and find equilibrium.

Comment: Why the boost converter? Why not just let the buck-boost step up the voltage directly to the battery?